# C++ and Boost XML archive (serialization): Can I specify the tag name for elements? (default: "item")

Tags: c++, xml, serialization, boost

I want to serialize an STL container (specifically std::set) to XML.

I happen to be using boost, and I can't find a way of choosing names for some tags - specifically, tags representing an item in a container.

I'm doing that like this:

```
std::set<something> my_set; // populate it somehow too
std::stringstream oss;
{
    boost::archive::xml_oarchive oa(oss, boost::archive::no_header);
    oa << boost::serialization::make_nvp("Things", my_set);
}
```

And this generates a `<Things> </Things>` string with the elements of my_set as `<item>` tags.
Something like this:

```
<Things>
    <item>element of set</item>
    <item>another first element of set</item>
</Things>
```

Is there a way to control what tag is used for the "item" tags there?

I know that serialization is primarily used for round-tripping, and XML tag names are largely arbitrary in this use case.
However, I'm trying to get a cheap "toXMLRecursive()" function by piggy backing on boost archive. If it turns out that this isn't possible, I will use another approach (like manually construct the XML with rapidxml or similar).

edit: it seems like the quick-and-dirty solution is just to specialize the serialize function to loop over items and choose the 'nvp' ourselves (ie, re-implement serialization of sets) like this:

```
template <typename Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, MySetType & me, const unsigned int /*version*/)
{
    for (auto & el : me){
        ar & boost::serialization::make_nvp("MyElementName", el);
    }
}
```

... but I was hoping for another way that didn't mean I had to reimplement the serialization of all STL classes in use in my project (and what if two typedefs clash? Have to do some careful organization of the code!).

Comment: I don't believe this is possible (other than to rewrite the serialization code for STL collections). See the code in boost/serialization/collections_save_imp.hpp. Here in the function template save_collection, the tag for each item of the collection is hard-coded to "item".

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own serialization wrapper

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/serialization/doc/wrappers.html

You can look at the implementation of `boost/serialization/set.hpp` and basically copy/paste the parts you want and then change according to taste.

HOWEVER. It seems you're trying to control the archive format incidentals. They shouldn't matter to you. If the other end **does not use Boost** to read your archive, stop what you're doing and redesign.

Use protobuf, your own XML schema with a proper XML library, another serialization format that you can document etc.